# Apache Guacamole Invalid Login

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8, guacamole

Very new to Guacamole but I do understand how it works. I'm fairly certain I've installed and configured everything correctly but I am getting an invalid login message when I try to log in, even with the default user-mapping.xml.

I've set the $GUACAMOLE_HOME variable to the following:

```
/etc/guacamole/
```

guacamole.properties is as follows:

```
# Hostname and port of guacamole proxy
guacd-hostname: localhost
guacd-port:     4822

# Auth provider class (authenticates user/pass combination, needed if using the provided login screen)
auth-provider: net.sourceforge.guacamole.net.basic.BasicFileAuthenticationProvider
basic-user-mapping: /etc/guacamole/user-mapping.xml
```

And my user-mapping.xml is as follows:

```
<user-mapping>

<!-- Example user configurations are given below. For more information,
     see the user-mapping.xml section of the Guacamole configuration
     documentation: http://guac-dev.org/Configuring%20Guacamole -->

<!-- Per-user authentication and config information -->
<!--
<authorize username="USER1" password="PASSWORD">
    <protocol>rdp</protocol>
    <param name="hostname">192.168.1.90</param>
    <param name="port">3389</param>
</authorize>
-->

<!-- Another user, but using md5 to hash the password
     (example below uses the md5 hash of "PASSWORD") -->
<!--
<authorize
        username="USERNAME2"
        password="319f4d26e3c536b5dd871bb2c52e3178"
        encoding="md5">
    <protocol>vnc</protocol>
    <param name="hostname">localhost</param>
    <param name="port">5901</param>
    <param name="password">VNCPASS</param>
</authorize>
-->

</user-mapping>
```

An ls -la on ~/tomcat8/.guacamole/ gives me the following:

```
guacamole.properties -> /etc/guacamole/guacamole.properties
```

And the log files show the user-mapping.xml file is being read by tomcat:

```
Nov 02, 2019 1:49:17 PM net.sourceforge.guacamole.net.basic.BasicFileAuthenticationProvider info
INFO: Reading user mapping file: /etc/guacamole/user-mapping.xml
Nov 02, 2019 1:49:17 PM org.glyptodon.guacamole.net.basic.AuthenticatingHttpServlet warn
WARNING: Authentication attempt from 192.168.1.115 for user "USER1" failed.
Nov 02, 2019 1:49:17 PM org.glyptodon.guacamole.net.basic.AuthenticatingHttpServlet warn
WARNING: Permission denied: Not authenticated
```

As I said, even if I use the default user-mapping.xml with USERNAME & PASSWORD, I still get the same error.

**Environment is as follows:**

Ubuntu 16.04

Tomcat8

openjdk version "1.8.0_222"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1-b10)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)

Guacamole proxy daemon (guacd) version 0.8.3

Answer (score 0):

Your user-mapping.xml contains no valid user. The users you have are commented (between ).

You just need to uncomment the user you need.